# how to include several count functions and group byes in one line

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I am trying to get the number of customers by their types and  groups all in line as such:

GroupName | GroupNotes | Count(Type1) | Count(Type2) | Count(Type3)

but instead I can only get the groupid ,the typeid and the number of types in the group by using the following query

```
SELECT
  CustomersGroups.idCustomerGroup , Customers.type , COUNT(*)
FROM
  CustomersGroups 
    inner Join CustomersInGroup on CustomersGroups.idCustomerGroup = CustomersInGroup.idCustomerGroup
    inner Join Customers on Customers.idCustomer = CustomersInGroup.idCustomer 
Group by 
  CustomersGroups.idCustomerGroup, Customers.type
```

is there a way to show them in a single line , (and show the name of the group?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "pivot" query.  Some databases directly support `pivot` syntax.  In all, you can use conditional aggregation.

Perhaps more importantly, you should learn to use table aliases.  These make queries easier to write and to read:

```
select cg.idCustomerGroup, 
       sum(case when c.type = 'Type1' then 1 else 0 end) as num_type1,
       sum(case when c.type = 'Type2' then 1 else 0 end) as num_type2,
       sum(case when c.type = 'Type3' then 1 else 0 end) as num_type3
from CustomersGroups cg inner Join
     CustomersInGroup cig
     on cg.idCustomerGroup = cig.idCustomerGroup inner Join
     Customers c
     on c.idCustomer = cig.idCustomer
Group by cg.idCustomerGroup;
```

Comment: sorry for not using aliases I will definitely consider using the in future questions and thank you so much for answering :)